# VLC Always Fit to Window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, hotkeys

How can I have a shortcut key to toggle "Always fit to window" in VLC?

I tried searching in Tools --> Preferences --> Hotkeys, but no results for "Always fit to window"

It shouldn't matter what OS I'm on, but just in case, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Note: I will be toggling this feature multple times while watching a **single** video - I do not want to set a default when opening videos

Note: Preferably not a script in the background that detects when I press the combination

Note: Preferably without having to change the source and recompile

Comment: Double-clicking the window will make it go fullscreen, double-clicking the title bar will maximize the window - neither of which is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotkey: `o` (letter, not number)

Apparently there is a default hotkey for toggling "Always fit to window"

I accidently pressed 'o' and voila! "Always fit window" was toggled!

I looked through the list of default hotkeys, and 'o' was labelled "Toggle autoscaling"